# NSSortdescriptor not mixing lists

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I've got an array which should be sorted by name, but only the half of it gets sorted. I've got a list of entries which can be devided in two parts, the first part comes from a dictionary and only has the property "name", the second part comes from a core data database and got as well the property "addedByUser". both of the lists are inside the tempArray and get added into the _resultsarray, which then directly leads to the cellForRowAtIndexPath. But before, I try to sort _resultsarray by name. Now the problem occurs: first the list without the addedByUser attribute appears (sorted by name) and then the other list (with addedByUser attribute") appears, sorted by name as well. I can't get them to be mixed.

```
[_resultsarray addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];

// Sort the list
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[_resultsarray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort2]];
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Update: I'm very sorry, I forgot to write that both tempArray and _resultsarray are mutable arrays.

Update 2: It seems like it makes a difference if the names start with an uppercase or lowercase character. My updated question is then, is there a way to sort an NSMutableArray no matter if the words start with uppercase or lowercase character?

Update 3: I found out:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write an `NSComparoator` like:

```
_resultsarray = [tempArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
    NSString *name1 = ... ; // firstObject.name or firstObject.addedByUser
    NSString *name2 = ... ; // secondObject.name or secondObject.addedByUser
    return [name1 compare:name2];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
_resultsarray = [tempArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort2]];
```